# Analyzing the one-loop self-energy graph in $\phi^3$ model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-regularization

Consider the $\phi^3$ model with a real scalar field $\phi(x)$ in $3+1$ dimensional Minkowski spacetime with metric $(-,+,+,+)$. Its Lagrangian density is
$$
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi-\frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2-\frac{1}{6} g \phi^3,
$$
where $g$ is a coupling with dimensions of mass.

(a) Write down the propagator and the interaction vertex for this model in momentum space.

(b) Compute the one-loop self-energy graph using dimensional regularization.

(c) Introducing $m^2=m_R^2+\delta m^2$. What is the value of $\delta m^2$ if we want to write the one-loop self-energy graph as a finite function of $m_R$ ?

I think this problem has similarities with Peskin 10.2, and I think this might use the formula $\int d^d k \frac{1}{\left(-k^2-2 p \cdot k-M^2+i \epsilon\right)^s}=(-1)^s i \pi^{d / 2} \frac{\Gamma(s-d / 2)}{\Gamma(s)}\left(-p^2+M^2-i \epsilon\right)^{d / 2-s}$, but I'm not familiar with one-loop self-energy graph and cannot come up with more thoughts. So how to proceed with one-loop self-energy and where can I find more explicit explaintions about it?

Thanks!